# Error in UseMethod("group_by_") due to a 'character'

Tags: r, group-by, character

Hi everyone,
             I have a dataframe with a  responses for each row and several rows. My goal is to have % content in each district. I planned on having finding total content for each district and the total respondents of the study in each district.

This is the code I used:

```
jbnew <- jb %>%
   mutate(content = ifelse(jb$sum.contentcir > 3),1,0)%>%
   nrow(filter(jb))
group_by(wp$district) %>%
   summarise(Num.Totalrespondents =n(),
             Num.totalcontent = sum(content))%>%
   mutate(percent.totalcontent = Num.totalcontent/Num.Totalrespondents)
```

I keep getting this:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I'll appreciate comment on my code if it is addressing what I want to do.

Could you kindly help me solve this issue?

Comment: `group_by()` takes a dataframe as a first argument, not a vector/variable. Do `wb %>% group_by(district) %>% ...` or `group_by(wb, district) %>% ...`

Comment: Hi thank you, it worked.Can you tell me if ``` mutate(content = ifelse(jb$sum.contentcir > 3),1,0)%>%``` makes sense? I am also an error on that.

Comment: A key feature of `dplyr` code is that you are working off data frames. The process is `data_frame %>% group_by(some_var) %>% mutate(new_var = some_fun(old_var)` and so forth. You never need to call 1data_frame$variable` within a `dplyr` function. In you case you can do `jb %>% mutate(content = ifelse(sum.contentcir > 3, 1, 0))`.